# ZF2: Get module name (or route) in the application layout for menu highlight

Tags: module, zend-framework2, router

How can I get in ZF2 the current (selected) module name in the application layout?
Purpose: My application layout include the main menu of the zf2 app, and every time a module is selected I need to highlight the menu voice of the module. Also I need to set the correct route (url, action) when the menu is made with this for.
Every module has a menu voice:

```
<ul class="nav">
 <?php foreach ($menu_modules as $mod):
  $is_active = ($mod['name'] == $CURRENT_MODULE_NAME)?'selected':'';//GET MODULE NAME
 ?>
 <!--  class="active" -->
 <li><a href="#" <?php echo $is_active;?> ><?php echo $mod['title']; ?></a></li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>

 <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url('login/process', array('action'=>'logout')); ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Logout') ?></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="row-fluid" id="main_container">
    <?php echo $this->content; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

I know its too late to answer this question and also that there are a lot of answers available already but just in case someone views this question, it may be helpful.

In the primary or any Module's `Module.php`, write this -

```
class Module {

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {

        $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        $router = $sm->get('router');
        $request = $sm->get('request');
        $matchedRoute = $router->match($request);

        $params = $matchedRoute->getParams();

        $controller = $params['controller'];
        $action = $params['action'];

        $module_array = explode('\\', $controller);
        $module = array_pop($module_array);

        $route = $matchedRoute->getMatchedRouteName();

        $e->getViewModel()->setVariables(
            array(
                'CURRENT_MODULE_NAME' => $module,
                'CURRENT_CONTROLLER_NAME' => $controller,
                'CURRENT_ACTION_NAME' => $action,
                'CURRENT_ROUTE_NAME' => $route,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can use `$CURRENT_MODULE_NAME` variable in your layout file (as done in the question itself).
The rest of the variables mentioned in the above code can be used if required.

Comment: This worked great for me, with the modification as per the answer from Porta Tela Webbuilding

Answer (score 2):

I prefer easier way without dealing with `Module.php`

Place this code into **layout.phtml**

```
$routeName = $this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator()->get('Application')
               ->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
if($routeName === "users") ...
```

Comment: but this will not return the currect module name if we are in a child roudte. For example it can return MODULENAME/default

Answer (score 1):

Use **array_shift** instead of array_pop (Kunal Dethe answer):

```
$controller = $this->getParam('controller');
$module_array = explode('\\', $controller);
$module = array_shift($module_array);
```