# Zend Framework 2: Getting current controller name inside a module

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I'm creating a module X that will be instantiated inside a controller module. How can I get the name of that controller in a method of module X?

This module is **not** a controller, nor a view or layout.

An example. This is an action in the controller:

```
public function indexAction {
    $parser = new Parser();
}
```

And this my new module Parser, where I need to know the controller's name.

```
public function __construct() {
    $controller_name = ???
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just pass in the controller's name when you construct the `Parser`? e.g. `$parser = new Parser(__CLASS__);`

Comment: @Svengali I wanted to avoid such thing, just have a bare call to the class. But this could be a far simpler solution indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such dependencies you should use a factory to create your service instance. Then you can inject whatever you want in there, also a controller name. Your `ParserFactory` could for example look like this:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Application\Service\Parser

class ParserFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return Parser
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $routeMatch = $serviceLocator->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();
        $controllerName = $routeMatch->getParam('controller');
        $parser = new Parser($controllerName);
        return $parser;
    }
}
```

Your Parser class:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Service;

class Parser
{
    /**
     * @param  string $controllerName
     */
    public function __construct($controllerName)
    {
        //... use your controller name ...
    }
}
```

Register your factory in `module.config.php` like this:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Parser' => 'Application\Factory\ParserFactory',
    )
)
```

Get your service where you need it from the `ServiceManager` like this:

```
$parser = $serviceManager->get('Parser');
```

Comment: A factory, of course! *slap faces* Thank you, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been asked before but I think you do:

```
$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller', 'index');
```

You should just be able to grab it all from the router.

EDIT:

Yeah, check these out:

[How to get the controller name, action name in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883598/how-to-get-the-controller-name-action-name-in-zend-framework-2)

[ZF2 - Get controller name into layout/views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843092/zf2-get-controller-name-into-layout-views)

[ZF2: Get module name (or route) in the application layout for menu highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077159/zf2-get-module-name-or-route-in-the-application-layout-for-menu-highlight)

Comment: Again, my module is NOT a controller, view nor layout.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can still grab it from the router.

Comment: On that third link you've added, it's done on the module's Module.php file and added as a variable to the layout (using getViewModel()). I need to know the name to use it on my module's method, not its Module.php, nor a view, controller or layout.

Comment: You could get it from the router when your module gets loaded (onBootstrap), then set it as an accessible property of your module. There is a number of ways you could do this dictated by the needs and conventions of your application ...but they will all likely end up asking the router for the current controller.

Comment: Here's a random example form GitHub: https://github.com/srayner/CivAccess/blob/master/Module.php

You would do something like that but also fetch the current controller name from getParam().

Comment: Hmmm... if I get the controller name on onBootstrap(), how can I save and read it later on my module? Since, at onBootstrap() time, my module hasn't been instantiated yet.